# C++ string literal concatenate

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

I'm designing a logger using a macro. I want to concatenate the incoming log message with a constant string literal. If the log message is given as a string literal, there is no problem. However, if the macro argument is of type const char*, I cannot combine it. The problem is basically below. While solving this problem, I do not want runtime cost like std::string. Because I can concatenate string literals at compile time. I don't want runtime costs because LOG will be printed continuously. How can I solve it?

```
void foo(const char* msg ) {
    std::cout << msg << '\n';
}

#define TEST(message)  foo("hello " message)

int main() {

    TEST("world"); //ok. Output will be hello world.
    
    //...codes
    const char* msg = "message";
    TEST(msg); //error

}
```

I can do it by allocating memory like std::string and filling it into a buffer. But I don't want that.

Comment: you can't concatenate something with a variable at compile time, because values of variables aren't known at compile time

Comment: And variadic templates.

Comment: You could make `foo` a template accepting string-like objects. If you are going for speed, do not use `std::cout`'s formatting in the first place. Anyway, have you profiled the code and measured that run-time concatenation of `std::string`s is indeed the bottlenck?

Comment: You can use a sufficiently-sized static thread-local buffer to format your messages into before outputting. The cost of the I/O is far more than the cost of any copies. And if threads are involved, you must also consider the cost of synchronization. You can avoid dynamic allocation without using tricks like concatenation. Or you can embrace a _little bit_ of dynamic allocation by allowing your static buffer (which could be a `std::string`) to grow only when necessary. Best of both worlds, in my opinion (and personal experience).

Comment: is it actually a "problem" ? or are you trying to optimize something before measuring it? Remember that you can only possibly make something faster when you do already know how much time it takes. I'd be not surprised if it turns out to be insignificant. Though I might be wrong and the only way to know is to measure.

Comment: The slowest part of your code would likely be the call to `cout`, not concatenating a string ...

Comment: Does it *have* to be a macro?

Comment: Maybe, rewrite your macro and use strcat. Best would be to use C++

Comment: it is unclear whether a solution would be `#define msg "message"` or if you want runtime strings. String literals are not runtime strings. And in any case using macros is not nice. Really the only reason to use macros with logging is `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` but not with c++20 (`std::source_location`) and not merely to concatenate strings (because it doesnt need macros)

Comment: My compiler version is C++17. So, I can not use source_location.

Comment: The const char* value can come from a function. i.e ex.what() function can be return const char* value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it entirely without copying and without the possible performance hit from stream operators:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <concepts>

template <std::same_as<char const*>... T>
void foo(T const... msg) { // I recommend choosing a better name for this
  auto const putsnnl = [](char const* p){
    while (*p) std::putc(*p++, stdout);
  };
  (putsnnl(msg),...);
  std::putc('\n', stdout);
}

#define TEST(message)  foo("hello ",message)
```

Instead of concatenating just pass several pointers to const character strings. Unfortunately `std::puts` prints a newline after the string, so we have to `std::putc` all characters manually but that's not much different from what puts does, anyway.

Of course, with this you don't need to have macros anymore, unless you are doing something outside the scope of this question that requires macros. Your `TEST` can just be a free function.

---

If you want to use `std::cout`, it is even simpler and even allows you to log things that are not `char const*` but anything that `std::ostream` understands:

```
template <typename... T>
void bar(T const&... msg) {
  (std::cout << ... << msg) << '\n';
}
```

([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/voKbYraYT))

Comment: The solution looks good. Can I do that in C++17 without concepts?

Comment: @EnesAygün I am confused. Was it not a requirement to end up having a single `const char *` for an API call?

Comment: @nielsen I think this was an XY problem.

Comment: @EnesAygün Yes, just replace `std::same_as<char const*>` with `typename`. You wont have type checking, but that's probably fine.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. As you said, that was not a problem. So, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate them without paying some runtime cost but you can pass both strings to `foo` instead:

```cpp
void foo(const char* prefix, const char* msg) {
    std::cout << prefix << msg << '\n';
}

#define TEST(message) foo("hello ", message)
```